# Concat two column values data extention

Tags: marketing-cloud, ampscript, dataextensions, ssjs

I have a data extension and it has three columns .What I am trying to do is concat the two columns and add them to third column programmatically using AMP-script or sssjs like cl1,col2 as the value for third column.Is there any way to do it programatically.
Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use SQL Concat Function:

```
SELECT 
    FieldA, 
    FieldB, 
    CONCAT(First_name, ' ', Last_name) AS Full_name
FROM People
```

You can write back to *People* data extension, as long as you use Update, and not Overwrite setting in your query activity

Comment: Thank you very much